# :first-child selecting all elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Need to select only first option in select tag and give it different color than the others.

`:first-child`, `:first-of-type`, `:nth-of-type`

**HTML**

```
<div class="input">
 <select>
  <option value="" selected disabled>Your interests</option>
  <option value="" >Test</option>
  <option value="" >Test</option>
 </select>
```

**CSS**

```
.input select:first-child
{
    color: gray;
}
```

Need to make font color of only first option tag to gray. 
Using first child keeps selecting all option tags and giving them all same gray color.
Using bootstrap 4 if it means something.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? I already said and you can see in the test below that i need first one to be gray color. 
It is black color even with solution given?

Comment: your selector is wrong, you need to add a space `select :first-child` and this is what the duplicate is explaining

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply css to `option` not `select`

```css
.input select option:first-child
{
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <select>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Your interests</option>
    <option value="" >Test</option>
    <option value="" >Test</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I did do that and i get the same result like you. 
First option tag has black font color.

Comment: @pagani First option have grey Color when you open select box

Comment: yes i know that, but i need it to be gray from the start. 
I have already tried your solution. 
I need first option tag font color to be gray both unselected and selected.

Comment: @pagani you can not, but alternative solution you can apply black color to select and option with first-child to gray this will color grey which selected and first option also